# ESP8266 with on and off control via MOSFET

Tags: mosfet, esp8266

I would like to connect to internet an intercom in my home. For it, I will use an ESP8266 (ESP01-S), one MOSFET, and one optocoupler.

When one person touches the button, the optocoupler connects GND_esp with the GND_battery, then the ESP8266 turns on and the GPIO2 changes to HIGH for that turn on the MOSFET. The ESP8266 will send a notificacion to my smartphone and GPIO2 changes to LOW and turns off the ESP8266.

The battery is composed of 2 x AA. The MOSFET is a TN0110N3-G and the optocoupler is a TIL111M. The ESP8266 is directly connected to the battery.

My problem is that when I use the MOSFET, the ESP8266 will reset in a loop. If I wire both GNDs, then it works. This MOSFET has a Vgs of 2 V. The battery has 3.15 V at this moment. What do you think about it?

[image]

Comment: Please post a circuit diagram

Comment: The TIL111M is man-enough to do the job.

Comment: Two things to mention: 1. GPIO2 needs to be pulled high for the ESP8266 to boot into your program. 2. You better cut the ESP's supply voltage instead of its GND connection.

Comment: can you use a 2nd opto fed by GPIO2 instead of the FET?

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess the gate voltage on the MOSFET is too low.
Consider the following graph from the [TN0110N3-G datasheet](https://www.mouser.se/datasheet/2/268/TN0110%20C080813-948543.pdf):

[image]

At around 3 V<sub>GS</sub>, you can only draw around 300 mA through the MOSFET.
When using WiFi, the ESP8266 probably have current peaks higher than this, causing power failure and reset.

If it is only peak currents being high, not average, this could possibly be somewhat mitigated by adding some bulk capacitance on the ESP8266 power supply. Or look for another MOSFET, which can work with lower gate voltage. Or use BJT instead of MOSFET.

Comment: oh, I didn't see this graph , I will connect the gate to 5V and see if it is the problem. This morning, if I unconnect the resistor, the mosfet is always on and it works but I never can turn off the esp8266.Because of this, I didn't think that the problem was the mosfet. I will reply tomorrow with the result
Thank you!

Comment: Hi!, today I connect the gate of the mosfet to 5V and it works. Then I will buy other mosfet. I have seen IRL540.Do you recommend this mosfet for my project?
thank you

Comment: @Vmetal The same chart in the IRL540 datasheet shows that at 3 Vgs you can pull about 15 A through the MOSFET, so that should work better. Although, I would recommend that you switch on the high-side instead, there are some caveats when it comes to low-side switching a device like this.